# Yii with PostGis, select longitude and latitude

Tags: postgresql, yii, postgis

I am using Yii together with PostgreSQL and PostGIS in my application. I have a model "User" with a field "Location". The content of the Location-field makes no sense what so ever to a human, but Postgres can convert the value of the Location-field and turn it into Longitude and Latitude using the ST_asText-method. I have created dummy fields in my model for longitude and latitude. When i save my model, i use the beforeSave and afterSave methods to set location to it's right value.

My problem now is that i want the latitude and longitude dummy fields to be populated upon model creation (with existing objects in the db). I was thinking that there might be something like beforeSelect and afterSelect that i can use to append the query with an extra calculated column, and therefore be able to process the values returned from that extra column after the query has been ran.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this pretty easy. I was looking for a beforeSelect and afterSelect method in the CActiveRecord class when i should have been looking for beforeFind and afterFind.

Here's how i did it. Any improvement suggestion are welcome :)

```
public function beforeFind(){
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = "*,ST_asText(location) as location";
    $this->dbCriteria->mergeWith($criteria);
    return parent::beforeFind();
}

public function afterFind(){
    $location = str_replace('POINT(','',$this->location);
    $location = str_replace(')','',$location);
    $location = explode(" ", $location);

    $this->lon = $location[0];
    $this->lat = $location[1];
    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem with Yii2 and here is how I solved it.

1. Override `find()` method of AR and define your own `ActiveQuery` class:

   ```
   public static function find()
   {
       $query =  new MyActiveQueryClass(get_called_class());
       return $query->select('*, ST_AsGeoJSON(location) AS location');
   }
   ```
2. In `afterFind()` you will have geo-json and with that you can get lat/lng:

   ```
   public function afterFind()
   {
       parent::afterFind();

       $geoJson = json_decode($this->location, true);
       $this->lat = $geoJson['coordinates'][0];
       $this->lng = $geoJson['coordinates'][1];
   }
   ```

That is it for Yii2. Remember to convert your lat/lng to correct object before saving. Mine was geography column. Here is a bonus:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    //create field as expression
    if(!empty($this->lat) && !empty($this->lng))
        $this->location = new \yii\db\Expression("'POINT({$this->lat} {$this->lng})'");

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```